# How to modify numbers at the end of a cell using a formula

Tags: excel

I have cells in excel containing data of the form v-1-2-1, v-1-2-10, v-1-2-100. I want to convert it to v-1-2-001, v-1-2-010,v-1-2-100. I have nearly 2000 entries

Answer (score 0):

If all of the data follows the format shown then you could use FIND to return the position of '-'. There will be three instances of this character and you need to find the third one so use the position given by the first instance as the start position parameter of the second FIND and again for the third (essentially nesting FIND). Once you have the position of the third '-' you know where the final set of numbers are (from the returned third position+1 to the LEN of the string) and could use SUBSTITUTE or a combination of other excel string functions to configure the final portion as you need it.

I'm assuming that excel has your data formatted as text.

If you need further assistance I'm happy to knock up the formula in excel but I'm off to work now and won't be able to do so for around 9 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=LEFT(A1,6)&TEXT(MID(A1,7,10),"000")
```

Comment: please elaborate your answer

Comment: the position of the final "-" is not fixed at 6 for all data. So this won't work